# Can't 'fail' have noun as its direct object?

Tags: direct-objects

> He failed to appear.
>
> (1) ✲ What he failed was to appear. 
> (2) What he failed to do was
>   appear.
>  (Angela Downing, English Grammar: A University Course)

[Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fail?q=fail) has the case that *fail* takes noun phrase as its direct object(She failed her finals), but the book above says ‘He failed to appear.’ can’t be said as (1). Does the usage of *fail* without infinitive clause be limited only to certain meanings, like exams, tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failed can take a noun object, be it a regular noun or an infinitive:

> She failed her final.
>
> He failed to appear.

I think it's the "What" thrown into your example that makes it incorrect.  It's not unique to "fail"; the same applies to other words like "get":

> What she got was *her final*.  -- Makes sense
>
> What she got was *to appear*.   -- Does not make sense

You need a verb in the latter, and then you remove the redundant "to", like:

> What she got **to do** was *appear*.

Or in your example:

> What she failed **to do** was *appear*.

Answer (score 0):

"He failed French" is understood to mean "He failed (to pass) French" so the direct noun usage can only be used about things you can pass.

Comment: What about "He failed his family"? This doesn't mean he failed to pass his family, it means he let them down by failing to perform in some way. Would "his family" be a direct noun here?